# How to deploy a WebContent folder to tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a simple project in eclipse that only contains a `WebContent` folder with dynamic html pages (javascript, jquery, css etc).

How can I deploy such a project (that does not have a `war` file) to a `Tomcat`?

Comment: Try copying it to Tomcat's webapps folder.

Comment: zip the content and throw it in the webapps folder? havent done that before, just wondering if that might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WAR file is just a .zip with a different extension. You just need to make sure there is no top level folder within the .zip. Your files need to be in the root of the archive.

To deploy your static files you can either create a directory (the name of the directory will become the context path - use ROOT for the default web application) and copy your files to that directory. Alternatively, zip everything up, change the extension to .war and copy that to the webapps directory. The name of the WAR file (minus the .war extension) becomes the context path.

There are numerous edge cases and details associated with the above. For the full details, see the Tomcat docs:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment including the links on naming and expected behaviour.